# require js multiple optimized modules do ot work

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs, r.js

I'm trying to make a deployment version of my app with *r.js* and *grunt*. App is pretty complex, so I need more than one file in optimized version. In particular, a specific optimized module for each sub application and a bundle of common modules that are used in sub-application modules.

I have configured grunt like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    requirejs: requireJsBuildOptions
});
```

Here requireJsBuildOptions is a hash of module optimization configurations with *name* and *out*. Now it's working ok and building the modules. But I have some issues with autogerated require module names resolution. For example my current optimized module structure looks like this:

```
define('some/old/app/path/a', [], function () { });
define('some/old/app/path/b', [], function () { });
define('some/old/app/path/yet/another/c', [], function () { });

define([
    'some/old/app/path/a',
    'some/old/app/path/b',
    'some/old/app/path/yet/another/c'
]);
```

And define callbacks is never called when I require this module anywhere. But if I replace these long paths with simple:

```
define('a', [], function () { });
define('b', [], function () { });
define('c', [], function () { });

define([
    'a',
    'b',
    'c'
]);
```

the define callbacks are called. So is there any way to make it work with old long paths and why it does not work btw?

Comment: RequireJS is quite capable of working with module names that are paths. Everything you show in the question looks normal. Now, a good deal of problems with using RequireJS are caused by errors in the runtime configuration or in the build configuration or in how the HTML loads RequireJS and starts the application. So please add a) your actual build configuration, b) your runtime configuration, c) how you load RequireJS and start your application.